# User Authentication with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, authentication, password-protection

im new in hibernate.
I would like to build a simple autentication / login system in java with hibernate.

So let's say, i have a class User

```
public class User {

private int id;
private String username;
private String passwordHash;
...
}
```

Now i have a DAO to store a new User, and to get all users (as a list). Now im wondering, if its possible to get a list of users without the passwordHash field (for security reason)?

It would be nice if it was a question of configuration.

An other idea would be to split the User class into

```
public class User {

private int id;
private String username;
...
}


public class UserWithPassword extends User {

private String passwordHash;
...
}
```

So i could use UserWithPassword to store a new user into the database and use
the User class to query the list of all users (without password).

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Your split class won't work because you have to link a class to Hibernate.

Your DAO doesn't have to return the class itself. You can write an HQL query such:

```
select username
from User
```

See?

Then your DAO would have a method like public Collection getUserNames()

Comment: ok, thats clear to me, but i want not a list of usernames, but i want a list of User objects (with the passwordHash hidden)
by the way: I guess spliting the class would work with hibernates "Table per subclass" inheritance strategy

Comment: In that case you could map the derived class, then in your DAO, create the super class instances and return a collection of those. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: And what about the configuration? Could this solve my problem?

Comment: I think this will solve your problem, although I'm a little vague what you mean by configuration here. you would map Hibernate to UserWithPassword then write a DAO method that retrieves all of these classes.

Then you would loop through all of those and create new User(userWithPasswordInstance) and return those in a collection.

Comment: In addition, there's a mechanism in hibernate for mapping super and subclasses, but I've never done it. You might have a look at that. you might be able to map super and sub on the same table and read whichever one you please.

Answer (score 1):

you can use
java.util.List temp = hibernateTemplate.find("select u  from user u ");

you can take all user from temp;

but if you want authenticate,you can use spring security,i suggest